# How to avoid flickering when using an asynchronous binding

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, data-binding

I've created an example to illustrate my problem.

ViewModel:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _value = 1;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(1);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => { Value += 1; };
        timer.Start();
    }

    // OnPropertyChanged stuff ... 
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <namespace:VM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=Test}"/>
</Grid>
```

When running my application the text in the textbox flickers. During the update process the FallbackValue is displayed, which makes no sense to me.

Does anyone knows the purposes or what are the benefits that during the update process the FallbackValue is displayed? Is there a way to display the old Value during an async update process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an approach to avoid flickering by just inheriting from textbox and overriding it's textproperty-metadata.

**Custom TextBoxControl**

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    static CustomTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, null, CoerceChanged));
    }

    private static object CoerceChanged(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        var tb = d as TextBox;
        if (basevalue == null)
        {
            return tb.Text;
        }
        return basevalue;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <namespace:VM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <namespace:CustomTextBox Text="{Binding Value, IsAsync=True}"/>
</Grid>
```

It's important to have the text-binding **without** a fallbackvalue. So during update process the text is set to the textproperty defalut value - so in this case to **null**.

The CoerceChanged handler checks whether the new value is null. If it's so he returns the old value so that during update process there is still the old value displayed.

Comment: an interesting solution.. though I don't think it's accurate to say you're overriding here.. it's more like registering your derived type (a configuration concept) with a handler.. and you can probably put a resolver pattern to it. if you did `typeof(TextBox)` in your call to `TextProperty.OverrideMetadata`, would it still call the handler and provide the same result?.. if you specified both `typeof(CustomTextBox)` and `typeof(TextBox)` does the handler fire twice?

Comment: @BrettCaswell, it's not possible to use `typeof(TextBox)` - you'll get an exception. Because there is already metadata registered for the textbox textproperty.

Answer (score 3):

This seems normal to me, given that you are using `IsAsync=True` in your binding. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx):

> While waiting for the value to arrive, the binding reports the FallbackValue, if one is available

When the `PropertyChanged` event is raised, WPF initiates the process of updating the target of the binding. Normally this would happen synchronously, with the property getter called immediately to update the value.

But you are using `IsAysnc=True`, so instead WPF fills in the target with the fallback value, and starts an asynchronous request to retrieve the actual property value later. Until that request has completed, the fallback value is displayed.

> Does anyone knows the purposes or what are the benefits that during the update process the FallbackValue is displayed?

Per the documentation, the intent behind the `IsAsync=True` setting is that it's used when the property getter is, or could be, slow. Your code has told WPF that the property value has changed, so it knows the old value is no longer valid. Your code has also told (via the `IsAsync` in the XAML) that the property getter could take some time to provide the new value, so it defers retrieving that value until later.

In the meantime, what should WPF display? That's what the fallback value is there for.

> Is there a way to display the old Value during an async update process?

If you don't want the behavior that is designed for this feature in WPF, you should just retrieve the new data asynchronously yourself, and update the property via the setter when you have it. It's not a good idea for a property getter to be slow anyway, so this would be a better design in any case.

Comment: I agree with that. Though in my case I don't have a slow getter. As you can see the displayed value changes pretty fast. And in my real application a have several textboxes - so the view needs much time. With setting IsAsnyc=True I'm trying to avoid a freezed view. So in my case it makes no sense to have the FallbackValue displayed - it just causes flickering.

Comment: _"in my case I don't have a slow getter"_ -- then what's your motivation for using `IsAsync=True`? What "freezed view" occurs and why? WPF can easily display any reasonable number of text boxes and other controls without noticeable lag; by the time you have enough on-screen controls to slow things down, you have too many for the user to comprehend anyway. It sounds to me like your real question shouldn't be about `IsAsync` (which you probably shouldn't use) and instead should be about improving the user experience for your real-world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with an image source. I've removed the `IsAsync` on the binding and I have made my getter async:

```
// This field hold a copy of the thumbnail.
BitmapImage thumbnail;

// Boolean to avoid loading the image multiple times.
bool loadThumbnailInProgress;

// I'm using object as the type of the property in order to be able to return
// UnsetValue.
public object Thumbnail
{
  get {
    if (thumbnail != null) return thumbnail;
 
    if (!loadThumbnailInProgress) {
      // Using BeginInvoke() allow to load the image asynchronously.
      dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        thumbnail = LoadThumbnail();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Thumbnail));
      }));
      loadThumbnailInProgress = true;
    }
    // Returning UnsetValue tells WPF to use the fallback value.
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a binding will fail, failure is important to consider. Fallback value option presents users a message if an error occurs, rather than nothing happening. If you would like your fallbackvalue to display the previous value contained, I could think of a few ways of trying : possibly saving the value in a reference string and/or to another control, then binding to that control

But if you don't want the fallbackvalue displayed at all, you need to do a code inspection to see how your binding is failing/or is slow, and contain it in your code behind

Comment: His binding isn't failing. It's simply showing the fallback value until the property getter returns.

Comment: @Peter, that's just how I learned what a fallback value is, but I edited my answer to include slow response

Comment: @ManDani, I would go for Peters solution, but if you would like to stick with your way and experiment, try Binding the Fallback value to a hidden control that is saving a string of the previous value displayed

Comment: @JohnChris - you can't set a binding for FallbackValue, because it's not a DependencyProperty.

Comment: @ManDani, yep just saw, my bad

Comment: @ManDani, what if you just don't put a FallBackValue?

Comment: @JohnChris, without the FallbackValue the textbox shows the default value of the dependecy property. You can try it by overriding the metadata of the TextProperty and change the default value.